# read from stdin works differently in bash and zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, read

I'm trying to pipe a command's output to the `read` builtin of my shell and I get a different behaviour for `zsh` and `bash`:

```
$ bash -c 'echo hello | read test; echo $test'

$ zsh -c 'echo hello | read test; echo $test'
hello
```

Though that doesn't work in `bash`, the following works for both:

```
 $ bash -c 'echo hello | while read test; do echo $test; done'
 hello
 $ zsh -c 'echo hello | while read test; do echo $test; done'
 hello
```

Why is that? Am I using `read` wrong? I find it much more readable to use it in scripts in comparison to `test="$(echo hello)"` which forces me to handle quoting issues much more carefully.

Comment: see also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340928/why-doesnt-the-last-function-executed-in-a-posix-shell-script-pipeline-retain-v). notice that `bash` could be made to act the same as `zsh` in this case: `bash -c 'shopt -s lastpipe; echo hello | read test; echo $test'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing the results from what has not been standardized with POSIX.

POSIX does not standarize how the interpreter runs a pipe.

With the historic Bourne Shell, the rightmost program in a pipeline is not even a child of the main shell. The reason for doing it this way is  because this implementation is slow but needs few code - important if you only have 64 kB of memory. Since in this variant, the `read` command is run in a sub process, assigning a shell variable in a sub process is not visible in the main shell.

Modern shells like `ksh` or `bosh` (the recent Bourne Shell) create pipes in a way where all processes in a pipe are direct children of the main shell and if the rightmost program is a shell builtin, it is even run by the main shell.

This all is needed to let the `read` program modify a shell variable of the main shell. So only in this variant (that BTW is the fastest variant) permits the main shell to see the results from the variable assignment.

In your second example, the whole `while` loop is run in the same sub process and thus allows to print the modified version of the shell variable.

There is curently a request to add support to the POSIX shell to get information on whether any of the pipeline commands has a non-zero exit code. To achieve this, a shell must be implemented in a way where all programs from a pipeline are direct children from the main shell. This is close to what is needed to allow

```
echo foo | read val; echo $val
```

to do what is expected, since then only the requirement to run the read in the main shell is missing.

Comment: this is the text from the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) that supports this: "Additionally, each command of a multi-command pipeline is in a subshell environment; as an extension, however, any or all commands in a pipeline may be executed in the current environment."

Comment: The grammar in this answer twists and turns in a way, that is hard to make sense of.